# Problems with Resource Drawable Folders not being searched when building

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a Resources folder structure like this:
Resources ->drawable->drawable-hdpi (and others for the various densities and sizes).
Now I have a folder for layout-port and another layout-land
I am creating a splashscreen with just a background png file.
In each of the drawable folder the png file exists (with the same name)
I go to the background property of the layout and specify @drawable.splash.
But when I compile I get two errors ( one for each layout) stating- Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/splash').

Again that file is in all the folders, it seems as if the folders are not being recognized or searched.

Oh and here is part of my manifest

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

So I feel I have search the web and SO plenty but cannot find a solution to this.
Got to be missing something stupid.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: *drawable* and *drawable-hdpi* must be in the same structure level under your *res* directory. Like that: *res/drawable* and *res/drawable-hdpi*

Comment: Yup you nailed it. I did not notice that up front. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the `/res` folder only allows one level of nesting and ignores all folders that are not directly within `/res`.

[image]

Your /res structure should look like this, /drawable-hdpi is not nested within /drawable, but within /res.

Comment: Ok I matched that structure. However no joy. So lemme ask this, do the files need to exist in the drawable folder and then it android searches the other folders?

Comment: Ok - found out what the other issue was. The graphic supplied by my tech was called default.png. The word default seems to be a reserved word. When all the files in all the folders were renamed to default1.png all worked. Now the reason I caught this was that I flipped over to Visual Studio instead of Xamarin - during compile I received better debug / error information.